# text file to dataframe with a list column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to read in a text file like this:

```
exp1 sample1 2 5  
exp2 sample1 2 3 5 7
exp1 sample2 1 2 6
```

to a dataframe with a list column like this:

```
tibble(exp = c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3"), 
       sample = c("sample1","sample1","sample2"), 
       listdata = list(list(2,5), list(2,3,5,7), list(1,2,6)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    exp  sample   listdata
  <chr>   <chr>     <list>
1  exp1 sample1 <list [2]>
2  exp2 sample1 <list [4]>
3  exp3 sample2 <list [3]>
```

The purpose is to use the metadata in the first two columns to select and operate on the lists.

I can read in the lines as lists, but don't know how to separate the metadata:

```
listdata <- read_lines("list_c_data.txt") %>% strsplit(., " ") %>% tibble()
```

Any suggestions? I may need to read in the file line by line since the number of observations could be >100000 and the length of the list in each row could be >1000

Answer (score 2):

We read the file using `read.table/read.csv` with `fill = TRUE`, then `gather` (from `tidyr`) the 3rd to last column of the dataset to reshape it to 'long' format, grouped by 'V1' and 'V2', we `summarise` the 'Val' as a `list` and then `rename` the columns if necessary.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- read.table("yourfile.txt", header=FALSE, fill = TRUE)
gather(df1, Var, Val, V3:ncol(df1), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
         group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
         summarise(Val = list(Val)) %>%
         rename(exp=V1, sample = V2, listdata = Val)
```

---

Or we can `scan` to read the rows, `strsplit` by space, convert the elements in 'lst' (filtering out the 1st and 2nd) to `numeric` while we `rbind` the 1st and 2nd elements to a `data.frame` and create the 'lst2' as the third column.

```
l1 <- trimws(scan("yourfile.txt", what ="", sep="\n", quiet=TRUE))
lst <- strsplit(l1, " ")
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) as.numeric(x[-(1:2)]))
d1 <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst, 
                function(x) x[1:2])), c("exp", "sample"))
d1$listdata <- lst2
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Just tried both.  The first method is easier for me to understand, but `read.table` does not seems to handle varying list length well -- it truncate the longer list and start a new row instead.  I guess it uses the first few number of rows to determine the maximal number of columns to fill.

Your second method works well. It's just I am not familiar with the base functions -- they do not looks like something I can remember/master :-(

Comment: @Dong  I tried your example and used the `fill=TRUE` and was able to get the expected output.

Comment: Yes, it works for the example but will fail if the list lengths are "2, 4, 3, 4, 9, 3".  The line with list length of "9" will be folded to next line.  I think it is the algorithm that `read.table` uses to determine the number of columns without going to the end of the file.

Comment: One shortcoming of the second method is that the `lst` size become much larger (~10X) than the original file size.  It may become a problem once the files get large.

Comment: @Dong There is `fill` option in `fread` from `data.table` and it should be fast

Comment: It looks `fill` is not available in version 1.9.6.  However, the help mentioned a yet-to-be-implemented `sep2` argument which would handle list column specifically.