# set operation within a list column

Tags: r, list, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to do *set operations* between the vectors stored in a list column like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712196/text-file-to-dataframe-with-a-list-column).

```
DT  <- data.table(exp = c("exp1", "exp2", "exp2"), 
                  sample = c(1L, 1L, 2L), 
                  listdata = list(c(2L,5L), c(2L,3L,5L,7L), c(1L,2L,6L)))

> DT
    exp sample listdata
1: exp1      1      2,5
2: exp2      1  2,3,5,7
3: exp2      2    1,2,6
```

while very cumbersome, I can do

```
DT$inc = list(setdiff(unlist(DT$listdata[2]), unlist(DT$listdata[1])))
```

and obtain a new list column with the value `c(3,7)`.  But if I try to calculate the difference between the current row and the first row using

```
DT$inc = list(list(setdiff(unlist(DT$listdata, recursive = FALSE), unlist(DT$listdata[1]))))
```

expecting a new column "inc"

```
0
c(3,7)
c(1,6)
```

I get `c(3,7,1,6)`.  Apparently `unlist` flattened the whole list column together. Any idea what's going on?

I am also learning dplyr and data.table. So it would really help if you can provide solutions using one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] I try to calculate the difference between the current row and the first row

Well, you can do...

```
DT[, inc := .(Map(setdiff, listdata, listdata[1L]))]

#     exp sample listdata inc
# 1: exp1      1      2,5    
# 2: exp2      1  2,3,5,7 3,7
# 3: exp2      2    1,2,6 1,6
```

But I think it's far better to just not work with list columns.

---

Not working with list columns might look like...

```
DT[, r := .I]
DT2 = DT[,c(.SD[rep(.I, lengths(listdata))], .(v = unlist(listdata))), .SDcols=!"listdata"]

#     exp sample r v
# 1: exp1      1 1 2
# 2: exp1      1 1 5
# 3: exp2      1 2 2
# 4: exp2      1 2 3
# 5: exp2      1 2 5
# 6: exp2      1 2 7
# 7: exp2      2 3 1
# 8: exp2      2 3 2
# 9: exp2      2 3 6
```

Then we just work with this data set, and can do

```
DT2[!DT2[r==1L], on="v"]

#     exp sample r v
# 1: exp2      1 2 3
# 2: exp2      1 2 7
# 3: exp2      2 3 1
# 4: exp2      2 3 6
```

Comment: The answers come quick.  Can you explain use of `listdata[1L]`? The `dplyr` version below needs to use `[[`.  Also, I am not sure if it is a good idea to spread the list to multiple rows when the list length is very long.

Comment: @Dong Yeah, I was noticing that difference, too. `listdata[[1]]` (in Psidom's answer) is the first element of the lest; while `listdata[1]` is a *slice* of the list containing only the first element. So, if `Lst = list(11, 22)`, then `Lst[[1]]` is `11` while `Lst[1]` is `list(11)`. The `L` in `1L` just uses an integer version of 1.

Comment: The reason why I need one and he needs the other lies in R's concept of "recycling" and differences in the two functions we used. If you read about recycling and the docs `?lapply` and `?Map`, it should hopefully make sense. If not, maybe try out chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: Oh, and the reason to spread it to multiple rows is because that is how both data.table and dplyr are structured to work most efficiently and with the nicest syntax -- by grouping together rows.

Comment: Great options. Plus one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a corresponding `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% mutate(inc = lapply(listdata, setdiff, listdata[[1]]))

#   exp sample   listdata  inc
#1 exp1      1       2, 5     
#2 exp2      1 2, 3, 5, 7 3, 7
#3 exp2      2    1, 2, 6 1, 6
```